# Comparing SIFT and PolyPhen to other methods

Tags: snp

I'm looking for a database of nsSNP (non synonymous single nucleotide polymorphisms) and their effects. As I understand, the common methods to predict this are SIFT and PolyPhen, and I want to compare them to other methods.

The database needs to list the old sequence and the new one (or that I'd be able to infer that somehow), and their effect (whether harmful or not).

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly suggest you:

PredictSNP: It's the best tool for nsSNP detection as it compares and throw out result from all the tools available.

http://loschmidt.chemi.muni.cz/predictsnp/

Paper: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3894168/

[image]